# DNS error: when adding a subdomain using powerdns

Tags: centos, powerdns

I recently added a subdomain m.domain.co.za and it just does not show, I defined the domain on the apache hosting server and added the relevant dns records but somehow it is still not working. The root domain works but not the subdomain. I'm using powerdns on a centos machine.

Detail

When I PING domain.co.za it gets a respone. If I ping m.domain.co.za I get no response

The setup looks as follows.

```
record  TTL     TYPE            value
m   28800   CNAME       domain.co.za
```

On the hosting server my virtualhost file looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/m.domain.co.za
  ServerName m.domain.co.za
  ServerAlias www.m.domain.co.za
  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.co.za
  DirectoryIndex default.php default.htm default.html index.html index.htm index.php index.php5 index.php4 index.php3 index.shtml index.cgi index.pl index.jsp Default.htm Default.php
</VirtualHost>
```

the folder m.domain.co.za exists

http -t showed no errors

If I use nslookup

I get the following

```
work@work-laptop:~$ nslookup m.domain.co.za
Server:     10.0.2.2
Address:    10.0.2.2#53

** server can't find m.domain.co.za: NXDOMAIN
```

The live site is on the same server as the syub domain, that's why I used CNAME

Comment: We need more detail than this, what happens when you ping the domain? how have you set it up in DNS, is at an A record CName?

Comment: @Sam I added more details to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CName record currently looks like this:

```
record  TTL     TYPE            value
m   28800   CNAME       domain.co.za
```

it should look like this

```
record           TTL     TYPE            value
m.domain.co.za   28800   CNAME       domain.co.za
```

You need to specify the FQDN in the CName record.

Comment: I modified this and get Server cannot be found again

Comment: The serial never updated.